# Writing web crawler templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-crawler

I need to scrape a lot of different web pages for some data /and the best solution I can come up with is to write a template for every home page, is this possible or is there any better solution?

Comment: what do you mean by writing a template?

Comment: Every site's different and I need a template depending on how the source code looks. Choose a template depending on site >  scrap it > save the data on my server.

Comment: So you are thinking of identifying specific areas of target sites, where you extract data. so, for page x between the <h1></h1> tags etc.

Comment: Exactly. I know what i need to look for but don't think i can make a web crawler to automatic know what data it needs to get from every site. That's why i'm thinking of a template for every site or something simular

Comment: u can use portia tool for that, u can select the patterns u need to extract and generate a template from those.

Comment: @Yerken, well, it's not ruby on rails, but looks like the sort of thing he's after.

Comment: the crawler can be written in any language, the portia can be used as an interface for fetching the templates

Comment: as I understood he is planning to do that manually anyway, it is not an automated procedure

Comment: Correct @Yerken. It's a festival website and i want the admin to be able to fetch the bookings and schedule from the festival's official homepage on demand. Maybe i will use a cron job in the future but right now i just want to be able to create a template for every festivals homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution but i manage to get it work with `eval`

```
template = File.expand_path("../crawlers/#{@festival.name}.rb", __FILE__)  

if File.exist?(template)
    file = File.read(template)
    results = eval(file)
end

results
```